# how Entity Framework track the reference Id

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, identity, ef-database-first

I'm bit confused, how Entity Framework track the reference Id of any object.

Actually, I'm migrating data from one db to another. So, I have two Entities having master detail relationship:
1. QuestionMaster
2. ListName

QuestionMasterId is FK in ListName.

Now, it is not necessary for each question to a list, therefore, I have to keep on adding the questions into the QuestionMaster until I finds a question in which list is associated only then I have to create the ListName but corresponding QuestionMasterId should be assigned to ListName.

Following will explain it in detail, It was a complex code I have removed some of the code to make it easier to understand dont worry about the properties :

```
foreach (var Question in _tshQuestionMaster_local)
{
    // adding new question
    DataAccess.Hotel.DataModel.QuestionMaster _questionMaster_new = new DataAccess.Hotel.DataModel.QuestionMaster()
    {
        QuestionType = Question.TypeCode,
        QuestionText = Question.QuestionText,
        OrderNb = Question.OrderNo,
        Isactive = "Y"
    };
    _hotelEntities.QuestionMasters.Add(_questionMaster_new);

    if (IsQuestionHasList() && IsNewList())
    {
        //adding new list name
        ListName _listName_new = new ListName
        {
            IsActive = "Y",
            QuestionMaster = _questionMaster_new
        };
        _hotelEntities.ListNames.Add(_listName_new);
    }
}
_hotelEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Now, let say there are 10 questions in which list is associated with only question number 3 and 8. I should have the QuestionMasterId in ListName as 3 and 8 but it shows me 1 and 2 which makes me think that EF does not keep the references. Is it true? if yes, then what can be the alternative to get corresponding ids?

My model classes are:

```
public partial class ListName
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ListName()
        {
            this.ListItems = new HashSet<ListItem>();
            this.QuestionLists = new HashSet<QuestionList>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string ListNameText { get; set; }
        public string IsActive { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<QuestionList> QuestionLists { get; set; }
    }

public partial class QuestionMaster
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public QuestionMaster()
        {
            this.QuestionLists = new HashSet<QuestionList>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
        public string QuestionType { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OrderNb { get; set; }
        public string Isactive { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<QuestionList> QuestionLists { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: why have u commented `\\QuestionMasterId = _questionMaster_new.Id`? and it would be better if u share model classes as well

Comment: @TJ Wolschon, actually, I'm saving all entities batch at once so it works when you are saving each entity therefore it was useless let me remove it. Sure I will add the model classes too.